# How to pass touch event to a pie chart

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot

I am new to core plot framework and facing an issue:

i am CPGraphHostigView to draw a pie chart. As the `CPGraphHostigView` doesn't detect touch events i have an `UIView` on it which can detect touches. Now how can i pass this touch events to the pie chart so that `CPPieChartDelegate` method.

`- (void)pieChart:(CPPieChart *)plot sliceWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index`

gets invoked.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

-Ravi

Answer (score 1):

`CPGraphHostingView` inherits from `UIView`, which inherits from `UIResponder`. Therefore, `CPGraphHostingView`does detect touch events.

Here are the steps you should follow in order to detect touch events on your pie chart slices :

1. Add a `CPGraphHostingView` to your view in Interface Builder. You can achieve this by adding a simple `UIView` and change its class manually to `CPGraphHostingView`;
2. Declare your hosting view in the code:

   ```
   // In your view controller .h file:
       ...
       CPGraphHostingView *graphHosting;
   }

   @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet CPGraphHostingView *graphHosting;


   // In your view controller .h file:
   @synthesize graphHosting;
   ```
3. Make the connection with the IBOutlet in Interface Builder;
4. Initialize your graph and link it to the graph hosting view:

   ```
   self.graph = [[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame: self.graphHosting.bounds];
   self.graphHosting.hostedGraph = self.graph;
   ```
5. Initialize the pie chart and set the view controller as its delegate:

   ```
   CPPieChart *pieChart = [[CPPieChart alloc] init];
   pieChart.delegate = self;
   ...
   [self.graph addPlot:pieChart]
   [pieChart release];
   ```
6. Add `<CPPieChartDelegate>` to your view controller's declaration, and implement the method:

   ```
   - (void)pieChart:(CPPieChart *)plot sliceWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
   ```